# Show different div if returned data is empty in CI

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am new in PHP Code Igniter. How can I display different div based on returned data from model. If there are no data returned this div is returned

```
<div id='error_div' class='error'>No data here</div>
```

But if there is a minimum of 1 data. This div should be displayed:

```
<?php foreach($vendor as $result){  ?>
<div id='displayed_div'>
   <table id="table_list">
   <tr>
      <td>ID Vendor</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['id_vendor']; ?>" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Vendor</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['vendor']; ?>"</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<?php }; ?>
```

My controller to fetch data

```
    public function detailed_vendor(){
        $id_klasifikasi = $this->uri->segment(3);           
        $data['vendor'] =  $this->model_vendor->show_vendor_by_kls($id_klasifikasi);

        $this->load->view('view_vendor_detail',$data);
    }
```

This is my model:

```
function show_vendor_by_kls($id_klasifikasi){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('vendor');
        $this->db->join('vendor_detail', 'vendor.id_vendor = vendor_detail.id_vendor');
        $this->db->join('klasifikasi', 'vendor_detail.id_klasifikasi = klasifikasi.id_klasifikasi');
        $this->db->where('vendor_detail.id_klasifikasi', $id_klasifikasi);
        $this->db->where('vendor.st_aktif', 1); 

        return $this->db->get()->result_array(); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you're brand new on any *PHP Framework* or not using any frameowrk either, as long as the Server Side's Code is a *PHP language*, then checking using [**`empty`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) keyword on variable is acceptable after all:

```
<?php

if ( !empty( $vendor ) ) {
 foreach($vendor as $result){  ?>
   <div id='displayed_div'>
     <table id="table_list">
       <tr>
         <td>ID Vendor</td>
         <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['id_vendor']; ?>" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Vendor</td>
         <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['vendor']; ?>"</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
<?php 
 }
}
else { ?>
  <div id='error_div' class='error'>No data here</div> 
<?php 
} ?>
```

Comment: I thought I can do that in the controller. Thanks I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should check your return data before render in view file.

```
<?php 
if(!empty($vendor)) { 
foreach($vendor as $result){  ?>
<div id='displayed_div'>
   <table id="table_list">
   <tr>
      <td>ID Vendor</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['id_vendor']; ?>" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Vendor</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['vendor']; ?>"</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<?php } 
} else { ?>
<div id='error_div' class='error'>No data here</div>
<php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether it's empty or not :

```
if(empty($vendor)){
    echo "<div id='error_div' class='error'>No data here</div>";
} else {
    foreach($vendor as $result){
    echo "<div id='displayed_div'></div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if `$vendor` is empty before using `foreach` to iterate it

```
<? if( empty($vendor) ) {?>
   <div id='error_div' class='error'>No data here</div>
<? }  else {
    foreach($vendor as $result){  ?>
        <div id='displayed_div'>
          <table id="table_list">
           <tr>
             <td>ID Vendor</td>
             <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['id_vendor']; ?>" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Vendor</td>
             <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['vendor']; ?>" </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
<? }} ?>
```